# MySQL query with an operation based on an other operation result

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to do an operation based on an other operations result. Something such as:

```
SELECT
    SUM(first_column) as res1,
    SUM(second_column) as res2,
    res1/res2 as res3 
FROM my_table
```

But it seems that it's only possible to do operations on existing columns. What is the workaround for this use case?

Comment: can you mention the result set.. and the entire query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use subquery to achieve that.
Something like this:

```
SELECT res1, res2, res1/res2 as res3 
(SELECT SUM(xxx) as res1, SUM(xxx) as res2
FROM yyy) as subquery
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
SELECT res1/res2 as res3
FROM (SELECT SUM(xxx) as res1, SUM(xxx) as res2 
      FROM yyy))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT res1/res2 as res3
FROM (SELECT SUM(xxx) as res1, SUM(xxx) as res2 
FROM yyy))
```

This should work

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code blocks for your problem :

```
select t.res1
  ,t.res2
  ,t.res1 / t.res2 as res3
from (select sum(xxx) as res1
          ,sum(xxx) as res2
      from yyy) t
```

**OR**

Not recommended, but works.

```
select sum(xxx1) as res1
  ,sum(xxx2) as res2
  ,sum(xxx1) / sum(xxx2) as res3
  from yyy
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need the intermediary result, you can have better performances by skipping the subquery :

```
SELECT SUM(c1) / SUM(c2) AS res FROM t
```

Comment: Yes, but I need the three results...